# Asible - ERROR! with_dict expects a dict

Tags: ansible, configuration-management

> I am trying to create a keypair in aws using Ansible but it is
>   throwing me below error:
>   **ERROR! with_dict expects a dict**
>
> Below is my keypair.yml

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    region: ap-southeast-1
    keyname: aws_ansible
  tasks:
    - name: create a key-pair
      local_action:
        module: ec2_key
        region: "{{region}}"
        name: "{{keyname}}"
        state: present
      register: mykey

    - name: write private key to a file
      local_action: shell echo -e "{{ item.value.private_key }}" > ~/.ssh/"{{ keyname }}".pem &&
        chmod 600 ~/.ssh/"{{ keyname }}".pem
      with_dict: mykey
      when: item.value.private_key is defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Ansible 2.x so try:

```
with_dict: "{{ mykey }}"
```

If that still doesn't work update your question with the output of:

```
- name: create a key-pair
  ...

- debug:
    var: result

- name: write private key to a file
  ...
```

Comment: Accept this answer?